# Is it possible to find the list of methodcalls inside a particular method?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to list all the method calls inside a particular method. For example

```
public void testRunJob() throws IOException{    
        String response = JenkinsJob.runJobRemote("somevalue","somevalue");
        assertEquals("Created",response);           
}
```

Is it possible to list that `runJobRemote()` is the method which is used inside the method `testRunJob()`?. Can the reflection API help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Instrumentation APIs to figure out these kind of details and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection API does not provide such information. Use third-party [libraries to analyze class files](http://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries).

Comment: can u please suggest any specific API